# Динамический url rewriting в JSF приложении

Tags: java, java-ee, url, jsf, rewrite

Всем привет) Пожалуйста помогите решить задачу.

Условия:

Есть приложение написанное на JavaEE JSF. В приложении есть пользователи, у пользователей есть профиль, соответственно регистрация и идентификация. Приложение в стиле SPA соответственно есть всего две страницы на которых разворачиваются события. Первая эта страница регистрации/логина - my_site.com/login.xhtml, вторая это основная страница приложения - my_site.com/main_page.xhtml.

Задача:

Страница логина стартовая, поэтому также доступна по адресу my_site.com/, а вот страница my_site.com/main_page.xhtml, согласно ТЗ должна быть доступна по адресу - my_site.com/user_name, причем user_name соответственно для каждого юзера свой. Как это реализовать ума не приложу(

Есть замечательные библиотеки [prettyfaces](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) и [rewrite](https://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/)
которые призваны решать подобные вопросы, но к сожалению они только умеют на старте приложения формировать URL из переменной, например так -

```
<url-mapping id="userName">
    <pattern value="/#{ user.getName() }/"/>
    <view-id value="/main_page.xhtml" /> 
</url-mapping>
```

Результат мог бы быть положительным и на самом деле страница main_page.xhtml будет доступна по имени нашего пользователя при условии что мы знаем имя пользователя на старте приложения. Но его имя мы получаем из базы, только после того как он залогинился. Видимо урлы определяются во время деплоя приложения на сервер, потому что изменяя значение переменной userName(из примера с xml конфигурацией) нам НЕ становится доступна страница main_page.xhtml по новому имени.

Теперь снова вкратце -

Приложение развернуто и в работе, приходит пользователь на страницу логина, логинится. Мы подтягиваем данные о нем из базы и должны переадресовать его на основную страницу приложения. При этом в адресной строке у него должен быть виден URL состоящий из данных(его имени) которые мы только что получили из базы. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться `ResourceHandler`-ом. Не помню с какой версии в JSF появились ResourceHandler-ы, но в последней-то точно есть:)

Сначала составим простенький `ResourceHandler`:

```
public class UserPageResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {
    private final ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public UserPageResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewResource createViewResource(FacesContext context, String resourceName) {
        String remoteUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
        if (remoteUser == null) {
            // если никто не подключился, то ничего особого не предприминать
            return super.createViewResource(context, resourceName);
        }
        // Вычислить название страницы ползователя: /user_name.xhtml
        String userPage = "/" + remoteUser + ".xhtml";
        if (resourceName.equals(userPage)) {
            // тут и подменим /Василий_Пупкин.xhtml на /main_page.xhtml
            // т.е. запрос /Василий_Пупкин.xhtml обрабатывается как /main_page.xhtml
            return super.createViewResource(context, "/main_page.xhtml");
        } else {
            // во всех остальных случаях что запросят, то и выдать
            return super.createViewResource(context, resourceName);
        }
    }
}
```

Потом пропишем его в `faces-config.xml`:

```
<faces-config version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-handler>my.application.UserPageResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Если не ошибаюсь, `/main_page.xhtml` можно переместить в `/WEB-INF`. Чтобы не открывалась прямым запросом в браузере. Тогда надо изменить и код на `return super.createViewResource(context, "/WEB-INF/main_page.xhtml");`

Вкратце по второму вопросу.

Есть несколько способов.
а) При программной реализации входа через форму кнопка "Войти" может иметь примерно такой action-метод:

```
public String login() {
    ...
    // Код ниже должен выполняться при успешной аутентификации
    String remoteUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
    String userPage = "/" + remoteUser + ".xhtml";
    return userPage + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

б) При стандартном способе понадобится ещё одна страница. Пусть это будет `index.xhtml`. Его и надо указать в качестве wellcome-страницы, как это обычно делается.
Создать страницу `index.xhtml` с `viewAction`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{indexPage.init}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    ...
```

И сама viewAction такая:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class IndexPage {
    public String init() {
        String remoteUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
        String userPage = "/" + remoteUser + ".xhtml";
        return userPage + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

При успешном входе произойдёт два перенаправления вместо одного.
Сначала на index.xhtml и потом уже на user_name.xhtml.
Но пользователь всё равно этого же не заметит.
Только бы заказчик не заметил или не был бы против в крайнем случае.
`login.xhtml` -> `index.xhtml` -> `user_name.xhtml`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но задача состоит в том, чтоб в адресной строке было что то типа - my-site.com/pupkin и все без .xhtml. Ваш же вариант, почему то, позволяет реализовать задачу только в случае если идет обращение на pupkin.xhtml. 
Может быть вы знаете как обойти это ограничение?
И отдельное спасибо за <resource-handler>, я раньше о нем вообще ничего не слышал и не смог нагуглить после вашего ответа)) ни в одной книге, ни в одном туториале нет упоминаний о таком конфигурационном теге в faces-config.xml. Может поможите ссылкой на реурс с информацией?

Comment: Обзорные статейки по фичам JSF пипа Wtah new in JSF. Не редко упоминается в ответах на вопросы о загрузке страниц из базы данных например. Спецификация JSF. Чтобы не было .xhtml, может будет достаточно прописать маппинг в web.xml, `/*` -> `faces servlet` И к userPage в коде не надо добавлять xhtml

Comment: Весь день ждал вашего ответа))
назначить паттерн " /* ", это было первое о чем я подумал, но выяснилось, что нельзя его назначать, кидает исключение - 
"The FacesServlet cannot have a url-pattern of /*. Please define a different url-pattern." Да и не сильно изящный ход, абсолютно все пускать через FacesServlet. 
Может есть еще идеи?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438068/mapping-jsf-xhtml-files-to-no-extension Кстати автор ответа большой знаток JSF и вроде даже участвует в его развитии. У него есть сайт, где он статейки пишет. Сам использую его библиотеку OmniFaces